# Dropping rows based on complex conditions involving multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
aps1_risk.head()
Out[33]: 
   ID  class     S3   S22  S23   S26_3  S28  S29            
0   1      1  45698  1012  268  287230    0   10           
1   2      0      0     0    0  154298   86  454           
2   3      0    228   358  110  254892  128  202
```

In this given dataset, I need to drop all the rows where class = 1 and if any of the other variables = 0. I thought of using an if else condition, but is there a simpler alternative? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = aps1_risk[aps1_risk.drop('class', 1).ne(0).all(1) | aps1_risk['class'].ne(1)]
```

Alternative solution with inverting final mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~(df.drop('class', 1).eq(0).any(1) & df['class'].eq(1))]
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID  class   S3  S22  S23   S26_3  S28  S29
1   2      0    0    0    0  154298   86  454
2   3      0  228  358  110  254892  128  202
```

**Detail**:

Compare all columns without `class` if not equal `0` for each value of row by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.drop('class', 1).ne(0).all(1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Compare column if not equal `1`:

```
print (df['class'].ne(1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: class, dtype: bool
```

And chain condition together:

```
print (df.drop('class', 1).ne(0).all(1) | df['class'].ne(1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

So it filter `True`s:

```
df = aps1_risk[aps1_risk.drop('class', 1).ne(0).all(1) | aps1_risk['class'].ne(1)]
print (df)
   ID  class   S3  S22  S23   S26_3  S28  S29
1   2      0    0    0    0  154298   86  454
2   3      0  228  358  110  254892  128  202
```

Comment: hi @jezreal can you please explain the first part of your code to me?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows you to use very simple select syntax like this:

```
aps1_risk = aps1_risk[aps1_risk['class'] != 1]
```

or you can bombine more complex queries like this:

```
aps1_risk = aps1_risk[(aps1_risk['class'] != 1) | (aps1_risk.drop('class', 1) == 0)]
```

Comment: Right, but I need to look into the other variables as well.

Comment: Right,  Thanks    !